# Get User Profile using App Engine Endpoints

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, endpoints

I'm using GAE and endpoints with an Android application.

The user can sign in, but I would like to be able to get the user's first name and last name to be able to assign to an entity on the server.

I am also using authenticated endpoints so I have the user, however all I see if the user id and the email address.

Is there a way I can get the first name from the authenticated User?

Below is an example of the endpoint as I've set it up:

```
@ApiMethod(name = "getThings", scopes = {Constants.EMAIL_SCOPE, Constants.PROFILE_SCOPE},
        clientIds = {Constants.WEB_CLIENT_ID, Constants.ANDROID_CLIENT_ID},
        audiences = {Constants.ANDROID_AUDIENCE})
public List<Thing> getThings(User user) {

    List<Thing> response = new ArrayList<>();
    return response;
}
```

Comment: This sounds like something you will need the Google+ API for. Have you been able to solve this? if so, could you post a solution?

Answer (score 0):

You may get the user's nickname, is that OK for you, with getNickname().

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/users/User#getNickname%28%29

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I saw this, but it's possibly an email address so I don't really want to show this to other people. I'm wondering if I have to use something in Google+.